# How to implement Single-Activity with BottomNavigationView and hide it on certain screens in Android?

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, navigation, bottomnavigationview

How to implement Single-Activity using BottomNavigationView with fragment transitions? I would like the BottomNavigationView to hide on certain screens, such as 'CardFormFragment', to free up space for displaying content. What are the approaches to achieve this behavior and what are the options for customizing the appearance of BottomNavigationView? I would appreciate any help or code examples

after changing the texture to "CardFormFragment", the Bottom Navigation View will be hidden (set visibility(View.GONE)). Pay attention to any other navigator, the bottom navigation view is the display system (setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)).And it's not right there are other options

Answer (score 0):

You can add a destination change listener to the navigation controller.

```
navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener { controller, destination, arguments ->
    binding.bottomNav.isVisible = destination.id != R.id.cardFormFragment
}
```

the above code will hide bottom navigation view when you navigate to card form fragment.

Comment: I would like to like Instagram in the same place if the transition is to Direct, a new Fragment opens without the Bottom Navigation View

Comment: @NazirjonKadirov I've never used Instagram so I don't get what you want. But if you want to navigate to fragments where bottom navigation view is gone, you can change the code like `binding.bottomNav.isVisible = destination.id !in arrayOf(/* put no bottom nav fragment's id here */)`. If what you actually want is navigation to fragments where bottom navigation view does not exist, not gone, then you need to make a bottom nav fragment and set navigation for it. I think the latter case is more complicated for no reason.